# how to remove comma from dynamic react Material UI Text field loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native, material-ui, material-design

I have a query,

I am using React material UI Text Field,

while I am looping the text field from a dynamic array and I update the default value from the array, that time the default value coming along with comma(,) and the empty default value shows (,)

I have attached the code sandbox for your referral

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-wave-qv8je?file=/src/App.js

Comment: what do you want to show in placeholder? as it was id there integer

Comment: already placeholder is defined in the Input field. the comma is set as a Value, why the comma is coming like this?

Comment: GOPAL check my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
 const getDefaultValue = (event) => {
 const s = fdata[0].poititles.find((saveditem) => 
        event === saveditem.sTitleId
   );
   return (s && s.sTitleValue) || "";
  };
```

Working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-feistel-kjyv1

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
const getDefaultValue = (event) => {
    let res = "";
    fdata[0].poititles.map((saveditem) => {
      if (event === saveditem.sTitleId) {
        res = saveditem.sTitleValue;
      }
    });
    return res;
    // return ("test");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying comma because you are returning an array with two blank values.

```
return fdata[0].poititles.map((saveditem) =>
  event === saveditem.sTitleId ? saveditem.sTitleValue : ""
); // This is equal to ["", ""]
```

That's why when it is given to the defaultValue, it display a comma.
Might be better to validate it first.

```
let thisData = fdata[0].poititles.map((saveditem) =>
  event === saveditem.sTitleId ? saveditem.sTitleValue : ""
);

if(thisData === ["", ""]){
  return ""
}

return thisData;
```