# Remove comma appearing before/after default value string in textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I want to retrieve the name of the sequence that match with their value (inside the localStorage). I'd like to understand why is this returning the expected name (string) along with a comma, and how to fix this. Thank you in advance

For example, this is what I get in the textarea (material-ui) value/placeholder: ("Drosophila,") and if I add more entries to the localstorage, the commas will add up (e.g "Drosophila,,,," or ",Drosophila,)

**If i call the function inside a div tag it works fine, but not on a textarea tag**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qIeH.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYfoC.jpg)
the div tag is the one below. I need it to be in a textarea like tag

```
    getSeq2Name() {
        var archive = [],
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0, key;
        
        for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
            archive.push( 'Sequence Name: ' + key + ' \n ' + localStorage.getItem(key) + '\n');
        }
        
        var mappedArchive = archive.map((item, i) => {
            var values = Object.values(localStorage)[i]
            for (; values.includes(store.getState().s2); i++) {
                return Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => localStorage[key] === values);
                }
        });

        if (!Object.values(localStorage).includes(this.state.activeSequence === 2 ? store.getState().s2 : store.getState().s2)) {
            return "Sequence 2"
        }

        return mappedArchive;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to come up with a work-around for this issue. Since I got the naming correctly with a div tag but not with a textarea tag, what I've done was make a div behave like a textarea. I did not change the functions.

The HTML (using react):

```
<div contentEditable='true' className={s.divtextarea}
     placeholder={"Sequence name: "}
     onInput={this.onChangeSeqName}
     style={{fontFamily: 'Courier New'}}>
          {this.state.activeSequence === 1 ? this.getSeq1Name() : this.getSeq2Name()}
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.divtextarea {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
   overflow: auto; 
   padding: 8px;
   width: 100%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font: inherit;
   line-height: inherit;
   color:#000;
   cursor: auto;
}

.divtextarea:empty:before{
   content: attr(placeholder);
   color: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mappedArchive = archive.map((item, i) => {
            var values = Object.values(localStorage)[i]
            for (; values.includes(store.getState().s2); i++) {
//set the return of this to a variable to see what you are recieving
                return Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => localStorage[key] === values);
                }
        });
```

```
  const data = Object.keys(localStorage).find(key => localStorage[key] === values);
//then you can console.log to see what you are getting, and then you can only return the names
//only return if data is truthy, or if you find some key being truthy
//otherwise return an empty string
//here is an example of what you might return
   return (data && data.key) || ""
```

grabbed from this answer:
[how to remove comma from dynamic react Material UI Text field loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64569320/how-to-remove-comma-from-dynamic-react-material-ui-text-field-loop)

Comment: I did that and did a console.log of data and data.key. For data i get the name correctly without the comma (although it i put return data i get the comma also), and for data.key i get "undefined". Any ideas?

Comment: so if you console.log data you see it correctly without the comma, but if you return data the comma is there?

Comment: Exactly... Also, if i do return (data && data.key) || ""  what i get is just the comma